# Hiding content divs with jQuery toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I am trying to show/hide some basic content divs.  I believe the problem lies in using the **.toggle** function, which is not an issue with the function, but I'm just not sure if that's what I want/need.  Currently, they work as I believe they are designed, ***show on click, hide on click***.  My problem is that I want the div to auto-hide if any of the other divs are clicked.  The following code only works to show the corrosponding elements when clicked, and requires them to be clicked again to hide:

```
$('#open1').click(function() {
    $('#content1').toggle();
});

$('#open2').click(function() {
    $('#content2').toggle(); 
});

$('#open3').click(function() {
    $('#content3').toggle(); 
});

$('#open4').click(function() { 
    $('#content4').toggle();
});

$('#open5').click(function() {
    $('#content5').toggle();
});
```

The issue is this - when you click the element for #open1, #content1 is shown.  YOU HAVE TO CLICK #open1 AGAIN TO HIDE IT.  Otherwise, if you click the element for #open2 without previously clicking #open1 to hide, both #content1 and #content2 show up.  I am pretty sure this is the nature of using **.toggle**  ...

I tried some varying combos of using **.fadeIn**, **.slideUp** and **.slideDown**, and **.slideToggle** but just couldn't seem to get all the content divs to hide appropriately.

So my question is, how do I re-write the above code so that ONLY the corrosponding elements are shown at the same time, without the need to click again to hide the div? *(In other words, when #open2 is clicked, all BUT #content2 is hidden.)*

Thanks!

Comment: Please, show us your html file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RodeoRamsey/a2a1yqqw/33/

Comment: @RodeoRamsey check my answer. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubq629v9/)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="open1" class="open"></button>
<button type="button" id="open2" class="open"></button>
<button type="button" id="open3" class="open"></button>
<button type="button" id="open4" class="open"></button>
<button type="button" id="open5" class="open"></button>

<div id="content1" class="content-div"></div>
<div id="content2" class="content-div"></div>
<div id="content3" class="content-div"></div>
<div id="content4" class="content-div"></div>
<div id="content5" class="content-div"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.open').click(function() {
    var idNum = $(this).attr('id'); //open1 or open2 ...

    // get corresponding content to toggle
    idNum = idNum.replace('open', 'content');

    // hide all visible content divs except current one
    $('.content-div:visible:not(#' + idNum + ')').hide();

    // show the current content div only
    $(idNum).toggle();
});
```

This code simplifies so that you dont have to duplicate your code for extra buttons/divs that you might add in the future.

**NOTE:** I would further simplify this and instead of using `id` I would use `data-index=1` or 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: lol.I do like your logic better than mine . It is lot more code efficient.

Comment: Thank you @GGio.  I will test this and update shortly!

Comment: Fantastic, that solved the problem!  Now, maybe you can help me with one more step that I didn't realize I'd have.  If you notice on my Working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RodeoRamsey/a2a1yqqw/39/ - I have another jQuery action that is triggered on toggle, and that is the "opening" of the door.  Is there any way to trigger that to close much the same way we have hidden the non-clicked divs? In other words if you click "1" you see the door open and #content1 shows up.  If you click "2" without "closing" #content1 (by clicking "1" again, can we trigger the door-close function somehow? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

you can add an if condition which checks for the toggled state of other divs and when they are visible then apply a toggle command using this...

```
$("OTHERDIVS").is(":visible")
```

like this...

```
$('#open2').click(function() {
       /* for statement 1 thru div count 
       if  $("OTHERDIVS").is(":visible") then .toggle them*/
       $('#content2').toggle(); 
});
```

the above code snippet is just a skeleton not actual code.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create some generic solution for this problem.

Check [JsFiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pza7vu70/1/).

The idea here is that you set `data-target` and `data-group` depending ono your needs in your project.